# Mergesorting in solidity programming language

Tags: algorithm, solidity

I'm studying the algorithms and couldn't figure out how to write mergesort algoritm in solidity, is there any gas efficient way

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how you tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us exactly what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. Give us a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Be sure to take the tour and read this.